# Piping of batch commands processing

Tags: string, windows, shell, batch-file, command

I want to know what is the output of below line. Please explain me each symbol. Line is extracted from batch file.

`'java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"'`

Answer (score 2):

First take a look on Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

`2>&1` redirects error messages written to error output stream **STDERR** to the standard output stream **STDOUT**. This results in getting standard messages as well as error messages written to same data stream.

The standard and error messages written to **STDOUT** of `java.exe` on printing version are used as input for command **findstr** by using `|` to get output just the line containing the version information and ignoring all other lines output by `java.exe`.

This command is obviously embedded in a **FOR** loop. Therefore it is necessary to escape `>` and `&` and `|` with `^` to get all those redirection operators applied to execution of `java.exe` instead of command **FOR** itself which would result in a syntax error.

Open a command prompt window and run there just `java -version` to see the version information output by *Java* if command processor could find a file `java.*` with a file extension listed in environment variable **PATHEXT** in current directory or a directory listed in environment variable **PATH** at all.

Next run in command prompt window `java -version | findstr /i "version"` to see what command **findstr** outputs on searching case-insensitive for a line containing the string `version`.

`2>&1` respectively `2^>^&1` is unnecessary in my point of view.

Comment: probably this was executed in for loop and that's why it is `2^>^&1`

Comment: Yes, @npocmaka, I think that too, there is also `^|`; particularly the enclosing singe-quotes `''` look like the command line was parsed by a `for /F` loop...

Comment: I wrote in my answer already that the command is obviously used in a __FOR__ loop. But I do not understand usage of `2^>^&1` on getting version of Java. Using `2^>nul` would be enough in my point of view to suppress the error message output by command processor if `java.*` with a file extension defined in __PATHEXT__ could not be found by `cmd.exe`. I don't see any real reason to redirect error messages to standard message stream other than suppressing the error message.